# Seleccion de dos campos de diferentes tablas, todo en uno

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo dos tablas en una BD. Una es la tabla de `vehiculo` y otra la de `vehiculo_especial`.

```
vehiculo
---------

pk_vehiculo     modelo    matricula    kms_actuales    prox_itv      prox_revision
-----------    -------   ----------    ------------    ---------     -------------
     1            Opel     1111ABC        200000       2018-03-29     400000
     2            Ford     3333ABC        100000       2018-03-12     200000


vehiculo_especial
-----------------


pk_vehiculo     modelo    matricula    horas_trabajo   prox_itv      prox_revision
-----------    -------   ----------    ------------    ---------     -------------
     1         Tractor     2222ABC        20:00:00     2018-03-29     40:00:00
```

Lo que estoy intentado es crear una consulta que me de como resultado lo siguiente:

```
modelo
------
Opel
Ford
Tractor
```

He intentado esto pero no me sale muy bien. Alguna ayuda??

```
select v.modelo, vs.modelo as modelo 
from vehiculo v, vehiculo_especial vs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo en ese caso es un `JOIN`, que no es lo que quieres. El `JOIN` combina los resultados de las dos tablas pero en la misma fila.

Lo que tienes que hacer es la unión de los dos resultados, para eso en SQL puedes usar [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

```
select modelo from vehiculo
union
select modelo from vehiculo_especial
```

Comment: Genial! Muchisimas gracias!!